# MySQL Server Time Wrong (No Timezone issue!!!)

Tags: mysql, time, mysql-workbench, unix-timestamp, difference

i just noticed that the now() function on one of my MySQL servers is a couple seconds behind the local time. The unix-timestamp seems to work right and the Time of the operating sytem goes right as well.
The Conversation of the unix timestamp to a formated date does not work.

The following **example request** shows the problem:

```
select unix_timestamp(), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), now();
```

**result**:

```
1422519597, 2015-01-29 09:19:33, 2015-01-29 09:19:33`
```

If u take the timestamp '1422519597' and put it in an unix time converter, u will get '29.1.2015 09:19:57 GMT+1:00' which has a difference of 24 seconds in comparison to the now() and from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) function .
The request was made via a remote mysql workbench and via phpmyadmin.

I already checked the global and session timezone which is configured right. But the timezone could not be the problem anyway because the difference here is in seconds and not in hours.

Please tell me what is going on here.

Best Regards.

**EDIT**

- Version of mysql Server is 5.1.41

Comment: 24 seconds was the UTC correction value until 2012. Co-incidence? What is the version of your MySQL server?

Comment: thanks for ur answer,
version is 5.1.41